# Is there a way to transform a three column data frame into two columns while using the same data in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame as follows:

```
id    day    count
1     mon    3
1     tues   4
1     wed    8
2     mon    6
2     tues   3
```

and I would like to transform it to look something like this:

```
id   mon  tues  wed 
1    3    4     8
2    6    3     NA
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: from `tidyr` and `dplyr`: `dat %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "day", values_from="count")`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Edit post, include code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end here are a few ways.  No packages are used.

```
# 1
xtabs(count ~., DF)
##    day
## id  mon tues wed
##  1   3    4   8
##  2   6    3   0

# 2
tapply(DF[[3]], DF[-3], c, default = 0)
##    day
## id  mon tues wed
##  1   3    4   8
##  2   6    3   0

# 3
r <- reshape(DF, dir = "wide", timevar = "day")
r[is.na(r)] <- 0
r
##   id count.mon count.tues count.wed
## 1  1         3          4         8
## 4  2         6          3         0
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "id    day    count
1     mon    3
1     tues   4
1     wed    8
2     mon    6
2     tues   3"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```